# What is the easiest way to connect a server and port for a project using the current requirements of mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, server, mern

Presently I am getting the below error:

```
(node:23292) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:23292) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
MongoError: failed to connect to server [dashboardcluster0.0k4xgh2.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND dashboardcluster0.0k4xgh2.mongodb.net
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:109:26) {
  name: 'MongoError'
}] did not connect
```

```
const url = "mongodb://<admin>:<pass>@dashboardcluster0.0k4xgh2.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(async () => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server: ${PORT}`));
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));
```

This is my code at present for my index.js file
with all of my attempts in the comments. I have been expecting that it says Server connected to PORT 1337.
the project is this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uoJ0Tv-BFcQ&t=6688s

Comment: dashboardcluster0.0k4xgh2.mongodb.net is not working, I think you should find working mongo db address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/), your MongoDB Atlas connection string should take the following format:

```bash
mongodb+srv://myDatabaseUser:D1fficultP%40ssw0rd@cluster0.example.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

For you that means:

```js
const url = "mongodb+srv://username:password@dashboardcluster0.0k4xgh2.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;
mongoose
  .connect(url)
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server: ${PORT}`));
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));
```

Please note the removal of the `useNewUrlParser: true` and `useUnifiedTopology: true` options. These were only valid for mongoose v5.x so you don't need them if you are using mongoose v6/7/8. As per the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html):

> useNewUrlParser, useUnifiedTopology, useFindAndModify, and useCreateIndex are no longer supported options. Mongoose 6 always behaves as if useNewUrlParser, useUnifiedTopology, and useCreateIndex are true, and useFindAndModify is false. Please remove these options from your code.

Comment: Thank you so much jQueeny! I am grateful to you for solving my problem, and shedding extra light upon the documentation. I have made the updates, and I will be mindful of these requirements going forward.

Comment: @HoshiHoliday. You're very welcome. If you found the answer useful please consider [marking as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.). Good luck learning MongoDB.